# QGIS label callouts anchor from the edge of the symbol

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, labeling

I am a beginner in QGIS. I'm using QGIS 3.32.

I have several rectangular symbols that are sometimes close together or overlapping. Each symbol has its own size (ellipse marker, width and height defined by data with expressions), with transparent background. All symbols must have their own label. I have moved by hand the labels of the most congested areas (see image, simplified example), but I still cannot optimally resolve callouts start anchor.

I have set the label placement in Cartographic, and distance offset "From Symbol Bounds", but I can't get the line to start at the edge of the symbol, it always starts from the centroid. With a little Pythagoras I was able to get it closer, but it's not perfect.

Is it possible to make the callout line start just at the edge of the symbol?

[image]

I read many answers about use Geometry Generator, but I have not achieved good results, I lack too much knowledge on that topic, and sometimes it's a bit confusing where to write the GG expressions.

Comment: You could convert your points to real polygons and then label those?

Comment: It is a layer generated from a CSV file, is it possible to convert them to polygons? I would like to maintain the possibility of editing the CSV data...but I can explore the idea.

Answer (score 2):

There may be several ways to put the labels outside the polygons, but I will suggest one method that could be helpful:

1. Right the polygon boundary and select `Duplicate layer`.

[image]

2. Put the duplicate layer on top of the original polygon layer
3. Activate Callout in the original polygon layer, and select `Point on exterior` from the `Feature anchor point`.

[image]

4. Go to placement, and under `Mode` in the `General settings`, and select `Outside Polygons`.
5. Set the distance to the desired offset distance.

[image]

6. For the copied layer (duplicate layer) created in the first step, go to labels, select `Blocking`, and under `Minimize placing labels`, select `Over the feature's interior`.

[image]

Here are the results before and after the blocking:

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Will this work with transparent polygons?

Comment: @Erik Do you mean transparent without fill color?

Comment: Idk, OP wrote "Each symbol has its own size (ellipse marker, width and height defined by data with expressions), with transparent background."

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have followed the steps, but I don't see the same options, such as "Outside Polygons" mode or "Over the feature's interior". I think the layer type is different. To clarify, the data source is a layer created from a CSV file that I update externally. Ideally, I would need to be able to make changes to the data and have them reflected on the map (like add new rows)